# COUNT statement in CHECK function

Tags: sql

Im working on a project and trying to achieve the following:
There is a table with stamps for a stampcard. However I want to add a check where a certain stampcard_id can only occur 5 times in the table.

I've tried using a CHECK CONSTRAINT with COUNT function

```
CHECK (COUNT(card_id) <= 5)
```

However this does not work as you cannot use an aggregate. Is there any other way I can add a constraint where for example card_id 67 can only occur 5 times in the table?

Comment: You could use a trigger, perhaps.

Comment: You can check when inserting a row using *not exists*

Answer (score 0):

`CHECK` constraints typically cannot perform subqueries. You do not specify which database you are using, but several databases allow you to implement complex constraints like this with triggers.

- MySQL: [Trigger Syntax and Examples](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html)
- Oracle: [PL/SQL Triggers](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/lnpls/plsql-triggers.html)
- PostgreSQL: [CREATE TRIGGER](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html) (search for "constraint")